# Can "possibility" be used with the subject which is a personal pronoun

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, grammaticality-in-context, idiomatic-language

> We have some possibility of canceling our trip next month, so we had
>   better not book our flight yet.

Could you advise me on whether the usage of the "possibility" in the sentence above, which I created, is correct? I think this usage is incorrect, but found the opinion on this [page](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/there-is-no-possibility-of-to.2448140/), saying that this usage is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely fine.
I might prefer "There is some possibility...", but that's just a question of style.